# Reading data from text files, assigning to arrays, and printing

Tags: c++

Just a disclaimer: this exercise was already due and I presented it incomplete, but wanted to follow up and understand my mistakes.

The requirements were to read the contents of two text files, assign their (floating point) values to 2D matrices, and print them to console. There was other requirements, but they aren't relevant to the issue at hand.

From my troubleshooting, there is either something wrong with the reading of these files, or something wrong with how they are printed.

Below is the contents of each text file:

file 1:

```
81.51310482 91.38325441 27.8637468  96.53709795
90.6244833  63.26754258 54.715496   15.76918882
12.70503097 9.75891752  95.79855889 97.10780782
```

file 2:

```
80.69838114 90.46987855 27.58524858 95.57220941
89.71869137 62.63518334 54.16861448 15.61157574
12.57804415 9.661377115 94.84105205 96.13721503
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
int r,ro,c,co,iter;
float ary,avg,a1[3][4],a2[3][4];

std::ifstream fs;
std::string line;
void assignarray(int iter,float ary);
void printarray(int iter);

int main(){
//select text files
for(iter=1;iter<3;iter++){
    if(iter==1){
        fs.open("table_1.txt");
        ary=a1[r][c];}
    else if(iter==2){
        fs.open("table_2.txt");
        ary=a2[r][c];}
if(fs.is_open()){
    //std::cout<<"File was successfully opened.\n";
    assignarray(iter,ary);
    printarray(iter);
    fs.close();}
else{
    std::cout<<"There was a problem opening or writing to the destination file, please try again.\n";
    return 1;}
    }
std::cout<<"Please input the coordinates for the row and column of both arrays, the entries of which will be averaged.\nInput format: R C\n";
std::cin>>ro>>co;
avg=(a1[ro][co]+a2[ro][co])/2;
std::cout<<"The average of the entries sharing coordinates Row "<<ro<<" and Column "<<co<<" is:"<<avg<<"\n";    
}

void assignarray(int iter,float ary){
while(std::getline(fs,line)){
    for(r=0;r<3;r++){//increment from row value 1 to 3
        for(c=0;c<4;c++){//increment column from 1 to 4
            fs>>ary;
            }
        }
    }
}
void printarray(int iter){//looks good
std::cout<<"table_"<<iter<<".txt contains the following values:\n";
    for(r=0;r<3;r++){
        for(c=0;c<4;c++){
            std::cout<<ary<<' ';
        }
    std::cout<<"\n";//line break after each row has been filled; creates columns
    }
}
```

Here is part of the (erroneous) output:

```
table_1.txt contains the following values:
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
table_2.txt contains the following values:
6.58383e-039 6.58383e-039 6.58383e-039 6.58383e-039 
6.58383e-039 6.58383e-039 6.58383e-039 6.58383e-039
```

The part I was testing out the most was the interior of the `assignarray` void function. I've done a lot of research to come this far, but it's the first time I'm applying most of these concepts; it didn't work too smoothly. Let me know what you think, and/or how I could rectify this. Additionally, let me know if there is more information I could provide for clarification.

Thanks.

P.S. For whatever reason, I'm not supposed to use C++11 or newer revisions. I would appreciate it if your suggestions keep this in mind.

Comment: It appears that you haven't given debugging this a try yourself, you present no evidence of an attempt anyway.  If you do that and step your code, you'll learn a lot - far more than we can tell you.  One hint, take a look at the initialization of all your variables. IOW, don't assume.

Comment: SO isn't a online debugging service. Please use a debugger first, and step through your code line by line to find out what's going wrong with your logic.

Comment: @Plasmarob Duly noted.

Others:
I have used the debugging features before, but my main method of troubleshooting is by printing to console at certain steps. Indeed I should practice both, but they achieve the same end, unless I am making a grave misunderstanding. I will give it another look.

This code is cleaned up for your viewing, and is the 6th complete restructuring of my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> The part I was testing out the most was the interior of the assignarray void function. I've done a lot of research to come this far, but it's the first time I'm applying most of these concepts; it didn't work too smoothly. Let me know what you think, and/or how I could rectify this.

It's not clear what you *wished* to accomplish in this function.

What does it do the way it's posted?

`iter` is not used in the function at all. It's not clear why you have it as an input argument.

`ary` is passed as a value. Any changes you make to `ary` are only local. It has no impact on the calling function.

```
void assignarray(int iter, float ary){
```

read a line. if reading a line is successful, enter the loop. The line that was read is not used anywhere in this function. The line is just read and discarded for all practical purposes.

```
while(std::getline(fs,line)){

    for(r=0;r<3;r++){//increment from row value 1 to 3
        for(c=0;c<4;c++){//increment column from 1 to 4
```

With the nested for loops, you are trying to read 3 x 4 == 12 numbers.
These numbers, if they exist in the file, are read into the variable but only the last successful read number is stored in ary. The rest are lost.

```
            fs>>ary;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only side effect of this function is that the global variable `line` has the contents of the last successfully read line in the conditional of the `while` loop.

The rest of the input is read and lost.

**Update**

There are a few things that need to be fixed for the program to work correctly.

And then, there are a few things that need to be changed to improve the quality of the program. Strangely enough, these changes will make the program easier to fix to make it work correctly.

1. Avoid global data as much as possible.
2. Use variable names that are more descriptive -- `array1` instead of `a1`.
3. Remove the `for` loop from `main` and replace it with couple of function calls.
4. Add white space around some of the operators to make the code more readable.

I can see `main` to be compacted into the following:

```
int main()
{
    float array1[3][4], array2[3][4];
    char const* file1 = "table_1.txt"; 
    readDataFromFile(file1, array1, 3);
    printArray(file1, array1, 3);

    char const* file2 = "table_2.txt"; 
    readDataFromFile(file2, array2, 3);
    printArray(file2, array2, 3);

    printAverage(array1, array2);
    return;
}
```

`readDataFromFile` can be:

```
void readDataFromFile(char const* file, float array[][4], int rows)
{
   // This avoid the global variable fs
   std::ifstream fs("table_1.txt");
   if ( fs )
   {
      for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
      {
         for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
         {
            if ( !(fs >> array[r][c] )
            {
                // Add code to deal with error.
            }
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Deal with the error condition.
   }
}
```

`printArray` can be:

```
void printArray(char const* file, float array[][4], int rows)
{
   // No need for global r and c
   std::cout << file << " contains the following values:\n";
   for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
   {
      for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
      {
         std::cout << array[r][c] <<' ';
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

and `printAverage` can be:

```
void printAverage(float array1[][4], float array2[][4])
{
   // No need for global ro and co
   int ro, co;
   std::cout << "Please input the coordinates for the row and column of both arrays, the entries of which will be averaged.\nInput format: R C\n";
   std::cin >> ro >> co;

   // No need for global avg
   float avg = (array1[ro][co] + array2[ro][co])/2;
   std::cout
      <<"The average of the entries sharing coordinates Row " << ro
      << " and Column " << co << " is:" << avg << "\n";    
}
```

With these changes, you would have completely eliminated all global variables. and program should be easy to understand and fix any problems that might have crept in.

Comment: "iter" was part of a previous revision and remains an artifact. As of now, this is the 6th rebuild from scratch, not including other minor revisions.

The idea was to read a floating point number from the text file, assign it to the respective coordinate in an array, and move to the next coordinate/number.

"reading a line" in the while loop with which void function `assignarray` begins was used to circumvent using an end of file condition, which I realized did not end on the correct value.

(continued)

Comment: The nested for loops should be indexing through the coordinates of an array and assigning the respective value from the text file. The major problem I was having was assigning them, as you have noted.

Should `fs>>ary` be replaced with something like `fs>>ary[r][c]` for starters?

Comment: Much obliged. I didn't expect such an overwhelmingly helpful response, that's for sure. I'll be studying up on the methods you used.

The majority of my trouble came from not knowing how to interface the different functions; the examples I studied had not prepared me for that.

I'd completely forgotten about the disadvantages of global data, glad you brought that up.

As for dealing with errors, I created a new function to be called from within void functions, as follows:
    int failstate(){
     return 1;
    }

Thanks for your help! One day I hope to be as proficient as you.